# What applications are exactly reading/writing my HDD in a given period? Application for statistics (on Windows)?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

### TL;DR

Could you suggest any programs that makes statistics (e.g. stored in files as logs) of what applications are exactly reading/writing my HDD **in a given period**?

### Longer explanation

Sometimes I hear my HDD clattering for a long time, which can also be caused by writing to or reading stuff from the pagefile (e.g. because of low free memory - I have 2 GBs of RAM, but on my Windows 7 x64, when using many programs, including some browsers with many tabs I sometimes run out of free memory, or have just little of it), but I would be curious if any other applications are using it too for example for writing temp files, config files, etc..

I can see the CURRENT stats in either Windows [Resource Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Monitor) or [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), but **I would like to restrict stats for a given period of time, and store it for later inspection**.

Comment: Life is short, get more RAM.

Comment: And preferably an SSD

Comment: @ChrisS, syneticon-dj: funny, but I'm curious to see the statistics for an EXISTING configuration, not the one I wish  had. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performance Monitor also comes with Windows 7.

1. Start logging with the System - System Performance log. It will run for 60 seconds.

   [[image: Screenshot of logging]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiQYH.png)
2. View the report. It shows which files are accessed most in `Hot Files`. You can click the `+` to the left of the file to find out which images (processes) are accessing it, and how much. You can also view which images (processes) read/write most to a specific disk in the `Disk Breakdown` breakdown section, just click the `+` to the left of the disk number.

   [[image: Screenshot of report]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiQYH.png)
3. For additional customisations, including logging time, you can create your own (`User Defined`) data collector. This is actually a rather advanced too, there is a **lot** of things you can log. I would recommend starting by basing off one of the System sets as a template, and just extending the time it runs for.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bob, I didn't even know this great built-in performance logging feature! Based on your answer, I've also created my first custom user defined data collector set where I could extend the 1 minute duration of the whole logging. Exactly what I was looking for!! This answer really deserves the 50 bucks and the acceptance (and also an upvote)! :D Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

Either the **[Windows Resource Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Monitor)** (built in)

[image: Resource monitor disk stats]

or the Sysinternals **[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)** in either the system information view for graphs

[image: Process Explorer system information]

or the main window with the I/O delta read/write bytes columns enabled for numbers

[image: Process Explorer list view]

will give you an ad-hoc view about what's doing which amount of I/O.

If you need exact throughput numbers per process or per handle, you would want to look at the per process read/write columns.

Comment: sorry for the late answer, and thanks for your post. I couldn't accept your answer yet, because to be honest, this way it's not too talkative. :) HOW could I make complete statistics of which applications exactly write/read my HDD, and in which directories? I haven't found such opportunities in Process Explorer yet... Please extend your answer with these infos, thank you! :)

Comment: You can see the files with directories using their Process Monitor tool.  Not sure about generating stats though.

Comment: @syneticon-dj: thanks for the updated answer (in the meantime, it was migrated to superuser.com :) ), my only problem is that I still haven't found any opportunity to create statistics files in a given period. Should I forget this opportunity? :)